# Linking IDE with right compiler for ARM cross compiling

Tags: compiling, eclipse, gcc, cross-compilation

I have installed Eclipse as IDE and gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabihf:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

to be able to develop code for ARM and cross compile it on my Ubuntu. 
But I don't know how to invoke gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabihf or link it to Eclipse IDE. Does anyone have experience on this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good article on this here:

http://derekmolloy.ie/beaglebone/setting-up-eclipse-on-the-beaglebone-for-c-development/